# mongoimport performances degrading over time

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm using `mongoimport` to import some `json` files into my MongoDB database. I have 5 files with about 2M documents each, and the collection have 4 regular index and 2 multikey ones.

When I start importing the first file I see ~500 documents inserted per second but the performances starting going down after a while. I'm now importing the 3rd file and I see a throughput of less than 50 documents per second. It seems like the import degrades with the collection size increasing. What's going on? How can I improve this?

Comment: how much RAM do you have available on this server?

Comment: around 100G still available, mongoimport is currently running and the ram utilization is not passing 20G. RAM should not be the issue here..  The totalIndexSize for the collection is less than 3G...

Comment: were you running mongostat during the import?  providing some of those numbers (for res and btree % columns specifically) may be illuminating.

Comment: I just did it, res=12g. I couldn't find the btree column.

Answer (score 2):

While it may not be the reason in this case, indexes do have some overhead when it comes to writes because you are inserting into the index as well as inserting into the collection.  There is an additional performance hit if you update a document that causes it to become larger than it's allotted size.  In these cases all indexes that include this document would need to be updated.

With 6 indexes on the collection, there is 6 indexes to update for every document that is inserted. This will have some impact on the effective speed of `mongoimport`

You could test this by importing into an unindexed collection and creating the indexes after the fact.

You can see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-do-write-operations-affect-indexes) for more information on write impact of indexes.

Comment: Andre, I see your point but it's also true that the 6 indexes are stored into btrees and updating those should not be too expesinve in terms of computation. The complexity of updating an index is log of its size and that hardly explains a drop from 500 to 50 documents per second when the collection size doubles... I tried creating the index after importing and the creation slows down in a similar way... BY the way, this is very interesting: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups thanks!